# Как получить JSON с помощью API key

Tags: javascript, json, api

Решил попрактиковаться в работе с JSON и решил в проекте использовать API OpenWeatherMap. При обращение к ссылке с JSON выбивает ошибку (из ошибки ясно, что надо использовать API Key). Как его использовать, вы бы не могли помочь ? Использую Java Script. Ссылка, представленная для API : api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139. Lat и Lon - координаты.

Comment: Ну вот же в документации написано: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&APPID={APIKEY}

Comment: Регистрация решит вопрос.